# How to retrieve a folder from the repository in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have the following code(s) in an attempt to retrieve a folder located in the repository root in alfresco:
**test-folder.get.json.ftl:**

```
<#escape x as jsonUtils.encodeJSONString(x)>
{"data" : 
        {
           <#if folder??>
           "folderName" : "${folder.name}",
           "folderPath" : "${folder.displayPath}/${folder.name}",
           </#if>
           "status" : "${status}"

        }
}
</#escape>
```

**test-folder.get.json.js**

```
main();

function main()
{
    var folder = companyhome.childByNamePath("Photo");
    if (folder == undefined || !folder.isContainer){
       logger.log("\n\n==>Folder is undefined<===\n\n");
       status.code = 404;
       status.message = "Folder " + url.extension + " not found.";
     }
     else{
         logger.log("\n\n==> Got the folder path: "+ folder.displayPath);
         model.folder=folder;
     }
    model.status=status;    
}
```

when I check the webscripts in the repo I get only the status code. further more neither of the logger messages are printed in the logs and no errors are showing in the logs.
Anything I'm missing?

Comment: is your "Photo" space directly under companyhome? your code looks ok. one more thing in status what you are getting 404 only? I mean as you are setting status always in the script keep one default value as well

Comment: One thing you said...you only get status code? You mean, you get an error status code?

Comment: No the success status code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I can advice you is to use the JavaScript Console developed by Florian Maul.

For me, It was a very useful tool.

You can know the result of your,"var folder = companyhome.childByNamePath("Photo");", just in a milli second.And you can just log the "folder[cm:name]" to view the results.

This link is useful.
[JavaScript Console](http://devcon.alfresco.com/berlin/sessions/using-javascript-console-development-administration)

Comment: Thanks. I had come across this and installed it for testing but had forgotten about this tool.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of possible issues:

- are you logged in when calling this webscript? Non-logged-in users might not have access to the "Photo" space.
- is your logging enabled? Try using logger.error instead of logger.log (or check your logging levels in log4j.properties).

Comment: Yes to both of your questions and nothing shows up in the logs either.